# DataSets based .NET programme: Use Designer tools or do it self?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ado.net, dataset

After thinking for long, I have decided to build my data app for the Not-for-profit organization I work for (I don't program regularly there, though...) using C#, .NET 3.5 (using ADO.NET DataSets) and Scimore db.

I have done base basic tinkering till now and have found this combo to be quite good and fast. Ya, "fast" is a requirement for me, as our computers are slow.

I have a question though: should I use Visual Studio design tools to help me build my GUI for data bound controls or should I code them by hand? In simple scenarios, I have found that designer generated code seems to be too big for the purpose.

Will it somehow affect the "fastness" of my final app?

Thanks for reading!

**Edit** Sorry, I didn't mention, this would be a desktop application, using Winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the amount of code does not affect execution speed so I shouldn't worry about that. Therefore, you should consider using the Visual Studio design tools for building your GUI. Most of the time you can build your application a lot faster this way.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to keep your ASP.NET code as lightweight and fast as possible you may want to look at using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).  This is the technology used to create StackOverflow, it gives you a lot of control over which data technologies you want to use to implement your site, and it for the most part avoids the overhead of using ASP.NET server controls.  You may find this to be a great option for your needs.

Comment: sorry, Adam, my bad. Didn't mention, I am using Winforms, as I don't want to get into trouble of all webserver etc.

Comment: No problem, since we're discussing desktop GUI I fully agree with and upvoted the other answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746508/datasets-based-net-programme-use-designer-tools-or-do-it-self/746530#746530